# Why is the /var/log/chrony folder empty?

Tags: linux, rhel, ntp, chrony

we are using chrony in order to sync our servers to ntp servers ( redhat 7.2 )

we configured the `logdir /var/log/chrony` in `chrony.conf`

and restart the chrony ( `systemctl restart chronyd` ) ,

but still folder - `/var/log/chrony` is empty without logs

what could be the reason ?

Comment: You probably also need a line like `log statistics measurements tracking`

Comment: ... and as described under [Why is the `/var/log/chrony` folder empty?](https://serverfault.com/a/985089/448950)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a line like this

```
noclientlog
```

then you know why the logdir is empty.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. I assume that the line in question would by found in `chrony.conf`, but for the sake of completeness, would you mind editing your answer to indicate _where_ (in particular if there can be multiple locations) the OP should look for that configuration line?